# Turn camera on remotely on iPhone

Tags: ios, camera

I know an app like this would NEVER get approved on the app store.
But being a developer, I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to turn on the device 
camera remotely.
it would be handy to use personally for security.'

EDIT: I would like to find a way without jailbreaking the device, 
     and I would guess with the new iOS 7, and multitasking there should be a way to create a delegate that should be able to turn on the camera to an app running in the background.

Comment: @rmaddy - why would you give a down vote without a comment?  I feel this is a logical question.  Now with iOS 7, and ability to have multitasking, I think its possible to have a delegate that would respond to a remote request.

Comment: Why would you assume I made the down vote? I didn't.

Comment: @rmaddy - I'm sorry, how do you see who down voted?  I saw that you edited the post.. but I see now you just changed the tags.  again I am sorry.

Comment: you can't see that. Ill tell you though I up voted it :D

Comment: @Daij-Djan - Thank you.  I thought it was a valid question.  and with the new multitasking in iOS7 I wondered if it was possible.   I would like to have an app that I could view the camera if it was ever stolen.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely not possible on 'regular' iOS for your app to come to foreground without some user action. It's also not possible to record video or take pictures in the background. This is by design.

If your app is running in the foreground, you're free to take pictures and video using `AVCaptureSession`. You can start and stop anytime you like and the user is not presented with any visual indication. I believe there are some home camera apps in the store that do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You could go the jailbroken route, and do what you like - but I don't know anything about that. Maybe someone else will.

Any non-jailbroken solution would have to rely on the app running in the foreground. If you can guarantee that, then you could enable the camera remotely by embedding a server within the app that listens for commands from a remote client. Once a command is received you could execute the code to open the camera.

As for taking a picture or video, I'm not sure what the options would be there. The standard camera picker views use Apple provided UI that requires the user to start the video or take the picture, but I imagine you could just create an AVCapturePreview layer and screenshot periodically it or something.

So in summary, there are solutions to this problem, but the more useful ones would rely on jailbreaking for full remote control.

Comment: You can automatically take photos using `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`.

Comment: I do not want to jailbreak my device.. I don't feel it's needed in this case.  As for relying on the app running in the foreground, this is no longer the case with iOS 7 and multitasking.  You should be able to send a delegate to your app that is running in the background and have it respond.

Comment: @Wain - Thank you for your answer, I've never really used the camera in an app.  I will do some testing with that.

Comment: "You should be able to send a delegate to your app that is running in the background and have it respond" - That's not exactly how it works. An app can do background fetches for information (e.g., Facebook requesting new posts) and the next time the app is launched the data will be there ready. It wouldn't work for your purposes as it doesn't launch the app with a UI - only minimal services run in order to perform the fetch.